# INDY 10 TIdTCPClient.Connect Causes Access Violation

Tags: lazarus, freepascal, indy10

I am simply trying to verify that an IP address and port is available. The TIdTCPClient.Connect(HOST, PORT) if it succeeds should verify that the IP Address and Port are available (according to my reading). It doesn't, as soon as the Connect is executed my application is abruptly terminated.

Using Lazarus 2.0.0RC3 on a Parallels Mojave VM. The Connect is in a DYLIB called from a simple test application. In the DYLIB, before I attempt a REST call, I verify IP address and port (that's the only thing I am trying to do). If I ignore the call to TIdTCPClient.connect the REST call succeeds (because I know the IP address is correct as is the port, I have the server sitting next to me). BUT for putting this code into the wild I wanted a way to verify that the server (IP address/Port) was available and pass back an error if not.

I have tried using an IP address, a valid URL (like Google.com) and a simple port like port 50. If I do not provide a port I get an error: 'A Port is Required'.

I have set the IP address and port using the TIdTCPClient properties, passed them as parameters to the Connect method all with the same (catastrophic) result.

```
function IsInternetConnected: boolean;
var
  IdTCPClient1: TIdTCPClient;

begin
(*
  Result := True;
  Exit;
*)
  // Verify internet available
  Writelog('DEBUG', 'Enter IsInternetConnected');
  Result := False;
  try
    try
      IdTCPClient1 := TIdTCPClient.Create;
      IdTCPClient1.ReadTimeout := 2000;
      IdTCPClient1.ConnectTimeout := 2000;

      IdTCPClient1.Host := 'xxx.xxx.xx.xx'; // This is a valid IP address
      IdTCPClient1.Port := xxxx; // This is a valid port address

      showmessage('B4 Connect');
      //IdTCPClient1.Connect(HOST_NAME, HOST_PORT);  // SAME RESULT AS SETTING PROPERTIES
      // THE FOLLOWING LINE CAUSES AN AV, KILLS THE APPLICATION
      IdTCPClient1.Connect;

      showmessage('After Connect');  // NEVER GETS HERE
      IdTCPClient1.Disconnect;
      Result := True;
    except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        showmessage('ERROR Failed to verify internet connection: ' + E.Message);
        Writelog('ERROR', 'Failed to verify internet connection: ' + E.Message);
        Result := False;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    if Assigned(IdTCPClient1) then
      FreeandNil(IdTCPClient1);
    Writelog('DEBUG', 'Exit IsInternetConnected');
  end;
end;
```

I should either get a Result of TRUE if the IP/Port combination is correct or False if incorrect or not that's the point of the exercise.

What I actually get logged in the host application Log is that an error is returned from the DYLIB (and AV), it then performs the finally block for the calling routine and immediately performs the finalisation section of the host program, ie. it terminates abruptly.

It should simply get back a response to say the call was unsuccessful and why (no internet connection).

Comment: "*before I attempt a REST call, I verify IP address and port*" - why? That is a waste of bandwidth. Just perform the REST call unconditionally and let it fail if the IP/Port is not reachable. There is no need to pre-validate beforehand, not to mention that is just a race condition anyway. The pre-validation could succeed and the REST call could still fail afterwards.

Comment: On a side you, you should swap your `try..except` and `try..finally` blocks, eg: `try IdTCPClient1 := TIdTCPClient.Create; try ... finally IdTCPClient1.Free; end; except ... end;` As for the `Connect()` AV, you are just going to have to debug into Indy's source code to find out what is really happening.

Comment: On the other hand, you should be concerned that your `except` block is not catching and swallowing the AV, it should not be propagating up the call stack. That implies a more serious problem with FPC/Lazarus's (lack of) exception handling on Mojave. Even Delphi has problems with exception handling on OSX, which affects Indy's use of exceptions for error reporting.

Comment: @Remy, thanks for the advice. I’ll look at not trying to validate the IP address: port and wait for the REST call to fail (if it’s going to fail). I don’t think there would be a race condition established, if the ip: port validate fails, I don’t try the REST call, but I see your point of caution.  And thanks for the other comments, yes the AV propagating back is a bit of a worry. Both Delphi and Lazarus seem quite immature in the macOS world.